# Python FastAPI: varying number of input items from a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I am trying to build a simple web interface (UI) for my API using `Jinja2` and `FastAPI`. A part of the UI including two inputs is fixed, but another part is created dynamically, by filling the `HTML` template with keys/items from a dictionary. For simplicity, I am using a dictionary with only 3 keys/items, but in reality, there could be, for example 8 or 11 keys and items.
I am struggling to collect the dynamically generated inputs because I am not sure how to do this without having to hardcode their names in the code. Below is an example of what it looks with hardcoded parameters in the function. Is there any way how to collect all the inputs at once and then somehow "unpack" them? I considered putting the inputs in an editable table, but then I am again struggling to collect the table's content.

This is the UI:

[image]

Here is the Python code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

dct = {"ctp_a": 1,
       "ctp_b": 2,
       "ctp_c": 20}

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates/")

@app.get("/form")
def form_post(request: Request):
    result = dct
    return templates.TemplateResponse('form3.html', context={'request': request, 'result': result})

@app.post("/form")
def form_post(
        request: Request, multiply_by: int = Form(...),
        # this is hardcoded which I don't like
        ctp_a_nm: str = Form(...), ctp_b_nm: str = Form(...), ctp_c_nm: str = Form(...),
        # this is hardcoded as well
        ctp_a: int = Form(...), ctp_b: int = Form(...), ctp_c: int = Form(...)
        ):
    
    result = {ctp_a_nm: ctp_a*multiply_by,
              ctp_b_nm: ctp_b*multiply_by,
              ctp_c_nm: ctp_c*multiply_by}
    
    return templates.TemplateResponse('form3.html', context={'request': request, 'result': result})
```

This is the html template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sample Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            
            <label for="multiply_by">Multiply by</label><br>
            <input type="number" name="multiply_by" value="2"/><br><br>

            {% for key in result %}
                <input type="text" name="{{ key }}_nm" value="{{ key }}" readonly />
                <input type="number" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ result[key] }}"/><br>
            {% endfor %}
            
            <br><input type="submit">
            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does defining it as a list work instead? i.e. `ctp_mm: List[str] = Form(...)` - you can then use zip (after validating that they have the same length) to get `text, number` entries back.

Comment: @MatsLindh this would certainly work, but I am not able to make it work. I tried to do ctp_mm: List[str] = Form(...)), but it gives me an error. It says that the name 'List' is not defined.

Comment: You have to import it from the the `typing` module: `from typing import List`

Comment: @MatsLindh: even after importing it it does not seem to be working. It says that ctp_mm does not exist.

Comment: I get it now. I need to reference the names in the HTML with the same name.

Comment: You use `ctp_mm` as the name for one of the fields and `ctp` for the other, then zip those two lists in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer builds on what @MatsLindh suggested in the comments.

The POST request part can be rewritten like this which allows for n number of keys/values.

```
@app.post("/form")
def form_post(
        request: Request,
        multiply_by: int = Form(...),
        name: List[str] = Form(...),
        key: List[int] = Form(...),
        ):
    
    result = dict(zip(name, [k*multiply_by for k in key]))

    return templates.TemplateResponse('form3.html', context={'request': request, 'result': result})
```

The UI needs to be changed in order to reference names and values with a unique name.

```
    {% for key in result %}
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ key }}" readonly />
        <input type="number" name="key" value="{{ result[key] }}"/><br>
    {% endfor %}
```